# Epichrome: custom rule for Gmail attachments

Tags: macos, gmail

I use [Epichrome](https://github.com/dmarmor/epichrome) to create a site-specific browser for Gmail. Clicking attachment icons in Gmail causes a new window to open in my system's default brower (Chrome), which I'd like to avoid. Epichrome Helper's "Custom Rules" should help here, but I can't figure out the right pattern to use.

Here are the two patterns I'm using:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/.*
https://mail-attachment.*
```

for both rules, set "And would open in:" to "Either" and "Then open it with:" to "This app". But clicking attachments still causes them to open in my system's default browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of Epichrome and have a Gmail SSB of my own. I've just confirmed that I'm able to view and download a PDF attachment from within the SSB without it trying to send the link to the default browser.

I don't have any rules specific to attachments, just a set of rules to keep Gmail links internal. Here's an export of my Epichrome Helper settings for my Gmail SSB:

```
{"ignoreAllInternalSameDomain":true,"optionsVersion":"1.1.2","redirectByDefault":true,"rules":[{"pattern":"mail.google.com/mail/*","redirect":false,"target":"both"},{"pattern":"accounts.google.com/*","redirect":false,"target":"internal"},{"pattern":"*google.com/contacts/*","redirect":false,"target":"both"},{"pattern":"*","redirect":true,"target":"external"}],"sendIncomingToMainTab":true,"stopPropagation":true}
```

If you want to try these, first export your own settings as a backup in case something goes wrong, then copy and paste my settings into a text document and import that into your Epichrome Helper on the options page. Choose "Replace" to overwrite your settings. Hope it helps!

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the help. (And for Epichrome!)

Comment: Glad to help! If you find bugs or have feature requests, please don't hesitate to open an issue on the project's [github page](https://github.com/dmarmor/epichrome/).